# Attempting to install libv8, "failed to build gem native extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using W7 64bit. Simply put, when I enter:

```
C:\Sites>gem install libv8
```

I get this result:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
which: no gmake in ("my PATH is here, and as far as I know it should include everything I need")
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.EXE: *** [out/Makefile.ia32] Error 127
Using compiler: C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\mingw\bin\g++.EXE
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=ia32 \
                  -S.ia32 -Dhost_arch=ia32


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/libv8-3.11.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.1
1.8.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling does not work.

I'm trying to install libv8 because it's a dependency for twitter-bootstrap-rails.

EDIT: As I said, I'm on Windows, and I'm realizing now that there's a filepath listed in this error as /usr/bin/env. So that's weird.

Comment: A couple of things: 1. Do you have gmake/python installed and in your path? 2. What are running the install in? (mingw/cygwin etc.)

Comment: I have python in my path, C:/Python27/. I don't know if I have gmake in my path because I've been looking all over to see how to install it. I assumed it was already installed and located somewhere with all the other gems. I think the install is running in mingw. If it helps, I installed everything with RailsInstaller because I could never get rubygems to work otherwise.

Comment: Check `C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\mingw\bin` for gmake.exe. If you can't find it there, this is what's causing the build error. Judging by the command line you've got there, you're running in the standard Windows command prompt. You should have either `msys.bat` or `git-bash` available. Try running the commands from there as it's much more reliable.

Comment: Is there somewhere I should be installing gmake from? Rubygems couldn't find it, so I downloaded GNU make from sourceforge, popped it in, realized it was named 'make.exe', renamed it, and now I get an error that 'libintl3.dll' could not be found, so that is probably not the best way to go about it either.

Also, I'm using "Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails"

Comment: According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubyinstaller/TkTCBm2TtCo), if you have the `therubyracer` gem in your Gemfile you should remove it as Windows already has a JavaScript Runtime. If that's not the case, try running the install from within msys (hint: search for `msys.bat` from the Start menu).

Answer (score 19):

The solution is to install version .0

```
gem install libv8 --version 3.11.8.0
```

until this is fixed, as I experienced this, too

Comment: gem install libv8 --pre worked for me, where without --pre it didn't.

Comment: for others looking for this answer: every now and then libv8 won't compile on windows. Just alter the version to some earlier version and wait until a fix is available. Also most gems try not to be dependend on this libv8, but it seems sometimes it's just pulled in by accident.

Comment: just make sure you have python 2 installed

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem, and @xiy above led me to the answer.  Had to change

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

to

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

as Windows does not need or like that gem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same windows problem that you described with:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

When I switched this the version from github:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :github => 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

No problem. Give that a shot.

Comment: gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' is the correct line