# gem install fails with 'patch' not recognized (windows)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, therubyracer

I am installing `therubyracer` gem on windows and get an error about "'patch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I need this gem because when I try to use less it says to install therubyracer.

Here is the complete output:

```
C:\>ruby --version
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]

C:\>gem install therubyracer
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150629-3268-otarv8.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
'patch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/patcher.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in patch!': failed to apply
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/patcher.rb:48:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/patcher.rb:48:in `block in patch!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/patcher.rb:44:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/patcher.rb:44:in `patch!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/builder.rb:57:in `block in build_libv8!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `build_libv8!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/libv8-3.16.14.9/gem_make.out
```

The log file mentioned contains no more information than the above.

I don't even know where to start working around this issue.

Note: I have ruby dev kit installed at `C:\RubyDevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2`

**EDIT:**

I'm doing all this because I am running [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and trying to use [Less for Jekyll](https://github.com/zroger/jekyll-less).

Based on some other [answers on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881175/268898), I installed an old version (3.11.8.0) of the libv8 gem. It installed correctly, but didn't fix the error. Looks kind of like therubyracer includes its own copy of libv8.

I installed ["therubyracer_for_windows"](https://github.com/eakmotion/therubyracer_for_windows) package.  But after that when I tried to run jekyll serve I got the error:

```
Configuration file: C:/data/adamantworks/Adamantworks.Web-jekyll/_config.yml
jekyll 2.5.2 | Error:  uninitialized constant V8::JSError
```

So it seems that one contains something outdated that is incompatible with jekyll. I uninstalled therubyracer_for_windows.

Comment: Have you tried running the command using Git Bash?

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem. Make `bundle update libv8` and its done ;)

Comment: That gives the same error with somewhat different paths